# java: executing cmd command to start-up emulator

Tags: java, android

I run this code in eclipse:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c emulator -avd OrangeAutoTest");
```

my application will hang up and i can't close the cmd-window

**i found the solution:**
i should run first like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K emulator -avd OrangeAutoTest");
```

the application will not hang up

Comment: Are you asking how you can close it, why you can't close it or what is wrong with your code?

Comment: it can start the emulator, but the application will hang up, it can't run the next java code, the application don't close the cmd-window, but i can close manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it works like this.

```
.exec("program args");
```

Therefore shouldn't it be:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c emulator -avd OrangeAutoTest");
```